# JGIt not cloning files apart form ones created in UI

Tags: jgit

i have pushed files using Push Command from local repository. the commit was successful and i could see the commit list in https://github.com/ . When i try to clone the same repository again, in my local folder i do not find all files cloned. the files that i pushed through my local folder is not seen. If i create a file directly in https://github.com/ only those are cloned.

Can anyone please help me with this issue as i dint find any materials related to this online. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Maybe you can share the actual github-project and some of your source code, otherwise it's hard to find out.

Comment: //code for cloning the repository

UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider upc = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(
    userName, password);
  git = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(remotePath).setDirectory(new File(repoDir)).setCredentialsProvider(upc).call();

Comment: //code for adding the file to remote repository
git.add().addFilepattern(fileName).call();
git.commit().setMessage("Added"+ fileName).call();
     
     PushCommand pc = git.push();
     UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider upc = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(
    userName, password);
        pc.setCredentialsProvider(upc)
                .setForce(true)
                .setPushAll();
        pc.call();
        git.getRepository().close();

Comment: Please note that ideally you edit your question with this information as comments do not show the information nicely (code formatting, ...)